# How to use Azure AD Authentication Library to sign in to WPF app?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory

The Azure sample [active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop) shows how to use [ADAL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/) to sign in for accessing a Web API from a WPF app. In the call to `authContext.AcquireToken` it's passing the Resource URL of the web service as a parameter. What if I just want to prompt the user to sign in to the desktop client itself and there's no Web API? Isn't there any sample for that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you define what do you mean in practice with "sign in to the desktop client itself"?. A native app will prompt you only when you need to access remote resources, because they are the only ones that the user cannot access directly. If a resource is already on your local PC, and you have access to the windows session, what are you going to protect with the login? In other words, what is the resource or operation that a user cannot perform unless they go through a login? Having access to the windows session means that the user can do pretty much whatever he/she wants. Doing a login without accessing a remote resource would largely amount to theater.

Comment: When the user logs in we allow them to connect to a remote database and work with data. On Azure AD we manage users and their access. Maybe we should pass Azure Graph API as the resource?

Comment: That is a good trick. How do you secure your connection to the db?

Comment: We read db credentials from the meta data we put on the AD instance.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure I understand. Usually metadata are publicly accessible - that's not where you'd want credentials to be stored :)

Comment: I mean custom attributes, user has to log-in to retrieve that through Graph API.

Comment: This shows that you do need a token for some resource (the Graph) hence falling back on the normal "sign in" flow for native apps. However: custom attributes are available by anybody in your organization - that's extremely dangerous to save secrets there. You might want to consider handling this via a custom web API, also protected by Azure Ad.

Comment: How about if I need to access office 365 documents, from a desktop app? Will I need ADAL library?